# Why sush tries to execute strings in my array as commands and how to prevent that?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mount, scripts, supersu

When running a script that contains an array in a variable, the strings in the variable will be executed as a command, I don't need anything inside the array to be executed as a command, how to prevent that ?

I get the error `sush: /su/su.d/1mount[5]: /mnt/runtime/default/MicroSD: can't execute: Is a directory`

```
#!/system/bin/sh
count=0
LOG=/data/media/0/Logs/MicroSD.log
PARTITION="/dev/block/mmcblk1p3"
TARGET={"/storage/MicroSD" "/mnt/runtime/default/MicroSD" "/mnt/runtime/read/MicroSD" "/mnt/runtime/write/MicroSD" "/mnt/media_rw/MicroSD"}
FSTYPE=ext4
VOLDBLOCK=/dev/block/vold/179:66
[ $(wc -l $LOG) -gt 5000 ] && sed -i "1,$(($(wc -l $LOG|awk '{print $1}') - 5000)) d" $LOG
echo "$(date) Starting..." >> $LOG
for m in ${TARGET[@]}; do
    mkdir $TARGET[$m] 1>> $LOG
done
contains() {
    string="$1"
    substring="$2"
    if test "${string#*$substring}" != "$string"
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
while ! ls $PARTITION
do
    count=`expr $count + 1`
    if test $count -ge 100
    then
        break
    else
        sleep 0.1
    fi
done
mount_partition(){
    ls -d $TARGET[$i] 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG
    if ! ls $PARTITION
    then
        echo "$PARTITION not found" 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG
    else
        while ! ls -d $TARGET[$i]
        do
            count=`expr $count + 1`
            if test $count -ge 100
            then
                break
            else
                sleep 0.1
            fi
        done
        sleep 0.5
        if ! mountpoint -q $TARGET[$i]
        then
            mountres=`mount -t $FSTYPE -o rw $PARTITION $TARGET[$i] 2>&1 > /dev/null`
            mountret=$?
            while test $mountret -ne 0
            do
                if contains "$mountres" "nvalid argument"
                then
                    echo "\n******************************************\n2nd partition filesystem is invalid\n******************************************\n" 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG
                    break
                else
                    count=`expr $count + 1`
                    if test $count -ge 300
                    then
                        break
                    else
                        if mount -t $FSTYPE -o rw $VOLDBLOCK $TARGET[$i]
                        then
                            break
                        else
                            sleep 0.1
                        fi
                    fi
                fi
                mountres=`mount -t $FSTYPE -o rw $PARTITION $TARGET[$i] 2>&1 > /dev/null`
                mountret=$?
            done
            mount -t $FSTYPE -o rw $PARTITION $TARGET[$i] 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG
            mount -t $FSTYPE -o rw $VOLDBLOCK $TARGET[$i] 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG
        else
            echo "2nd partition already mounted at $TARGET[$i] ..." 1>>$LOG 2>>$LOG
        fi
    fi
}
for i in ${TARGET[@]}; do
    mount_partition &
done
echo "\n******************************************\nMount output\n******************************************" >> $LOG
mount >> $LOG
chown 1023:1023 $LOG
chmod 770 $LOG
```

Comment: `sh` doesn't really have "proper" arrays, as I recall. [The man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh) suggests that expressions wrapped in `{}` will be executed (it refers to these as one type of "compound command"), so that seems to be what it's doing when you try to define `TARGET={ "some" "values" }`

Comment: You are correct, I had to resort to "set" command to have an array, it means I will not be able to have more than an array at a time, I hardly see how I will be able to compare two arrays in sh as it is. Sadly I cannot mark as answer a comment, please make an answer based on your comment.